# Can malware detect memory dumping?

Tags: malware, forensics, memory, volatility

Morning, I recently had need to check for malware on my PC by dumping the memory and searching for unwanted processes which could be malware, my question it's, is it possibile for malware to detect memory dumping, I am going to analyze the memory dump with volatility.
Will I be able to detect every process and don't let the malware hide itself, if it is able to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malware with sufficient access can do anything.  Including adjusting your memory dump to “skip” its memory… or give. A different memory.

As they say, as soon as it’s in…. All bets are off.